# Take different actions depending on jTextField value

Tags: java, if-statement, jtextfield

I have many more cases, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this. If the user enters 1 the program will convert from inches to cm, if the user enters 2, the program will convert from cm to feet, etc.

```
if (jTextField1.getText() == 1) {
    InchesToCm();
} else if (jTextField1.getText() == 2) {
    CmToFeet();
} else if (jTextField1.getText() == 3) {
    MetresToYards();
} else if (jTextField1.getText() == 4) {
    KmToMetres();
} else {
    jLabel8.setText("Error, try again");
}
```

Comment: If you have another question, post it separately. Don't just edit the body, or the answers will end out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of 'simpler' but you could use a switch statement. Like so:

```java
switch(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())){
case 1:
    InchesToCm();
    break;
case 2:
    CmToFeet();
    break;
case 3:
    MetresToYards();
    break;
case 4:
    KmToMetres();
    break;
    default:
        jLabel8.setText("Error, try again");
        break;
}
```

This way you don't have to use a chain of if statements but if it's simpler is up to you.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks that actually does help , and I am using Java. But for some reason its not working, i think its another problem so thank for your help :)

Comment: @user4978074 You're welcome :) and don't forget to close the thread if you issue is resolved.

Comment: For some reason I enter the case number into my jtextfield1 and then it keeps telling me its km even if i put 1,2,3  and the output doesnt even make sense :/

Comment: oh sorry I forgot something really important will update my answer right away.

Comment: @user4978074 The `break` statements are absolutely nessesary

Comment: ok thanks! another problem im having is when i put a number it does work except the numbers are confusingly off.. say i put 1 for the conversion choice (inches-cm) and then i put 5 inches, it shows me this: 12.7cm = 55.0 no idea why

Comment: Well that would probably be better suited for another question as I am not really into the conversion of inches to centimeters if you hadn't said so yourself then I would not have seen that that conversion wasn't right...

Comment: @user4978074 But I'll take a look anyway

Comment: okay sorry new to this forum site thing :P I just put the whole code I did if you dont understand ill make another post and see if anyone could help, you still did help so thank you :)

Comment: @user4978074 I'll look but someone else will probably spot it much quicker. And by the way remember to accept the answer to close this thread.

Comment: I rolled back the question so that this answer is no more out of context.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Right then I'll remove the disclaimer